# Recursive toString binary tree output

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, tostring

So I want my printout of my binary tree to read like [A B C D E F] but I keep ending up with an extra space and I can't use subString to remove it. What is the best way to approach this?

```
public String toStringInOrder() {
        output = "";
        output += printInOrder(root);
        if(output.length() < 1) {
            return "[]";
        } else {
            return "[" + output.substring(0, output.length() - 1) + "]";
        }  
    }

private String printInOrder(Node current) {
        if(current != null) {
            printInOrder(current.left);
            output += current.value + " ";
            printInOrder(current.right);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is removing the extra space at the end you could replace:

```
return "[" + output.substring(0, output.length() - 1) + "]";
```

with:

```
return "[" + output.Trim() + "]";
```

Another approach I might take is filling a List with the ordered values, and then you can have a greater control of how you format the ordered values as a string.

Comment: Using an additional ordered list when you're dealing with a BST, that is mainly thought to optimally perform ordered operations, doesn't seem to me a great option.

Comment: @Matt The function is already creating an ordered list, just in string format. By modifying a List object, you will be avoiding the string concatenation operations (which can become costly if there are a large number of nodes). Once you have the ordered list, you can do a lot more in terms of fancy formatting, and also make it easier to make use of a StringBuilder.

Comment: @Matt I was specifically instructed not to use trim or substring. Had to figure a traversal implementation to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use substring or similars, do a "look for maximum node" search (cheap log(n) operation), save that node and add an if statement on your output additions that checks if the node whose info has to be added isn't the last one. In that case, add the value without the space.

```
Node last = max(root);

private Node max(Node x){
    if (x.right == null) 
        return x;
    return max(x.right);
}

private String printInOrder(Node current) {

        if(current != null) {
            printInOrder(current.left);
            if(!current.equals(last))
                output += current.value + " ";
            else
                output += current.value;
            printInOrder(current.right);
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there are Big-O requirements for this assignment, so I can't add another search method. From the grading rubric:

toStringInOrder, toStringPreOrder, toStringPostOrder, O(N)
* return values enclosed in square brackets: [ and ]
 * Exactly one space separating the values
 * No space added at the beginning or the end
 * No use of String.trim or removing characters as part of creating the return value
An empty tree will generate a two-character toString value: []
A tree with the single string "A" in it will generate a three-character toString value: [A]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer I needed after some diagramming and trial and error.

```
private String printPreOrder(Node current) {
    if (current != null) {
        output += current.value;
        if (current.left != null) output += " ";
        printPreOrder(current.left);
        if (current.right != null) output += " ";
        printPreOrder(current.right);
    }
    return output;
}
```

Some changes to the inOrder and postOrder garners similar results. Thanks to all for the help!